# Fixing a simple slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how i can set  the slider to stop at the last item. Basically the slider still slides to left even though their aren't anymore items to follow.  Here is the link to my site.

http://federalland.ph/

The slider is located below the video presentation. Here is my code

### HTML/PHP

```
<!--SLIDER POST-->
<div class="row slider_post_container ">
    <div class="arrow_left">
        <input id="slide_right" type="button" value="Prev">
    </div>

    <div class="slide_post">

        <div class="slide_post_wrap">

            <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=9&cat=4');; if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) :the_post(); ?>
            <div class="slider_post">
                    <h2><a class="post_title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="post_thumbnail">
                  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); echo '<img src="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" alt="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '">';  } ?></a>
                 </div>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a class="read_more" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Read More">Read More</a>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>


        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="arrow_right">
        <input id="slide_left" type="button" value="Next">
    </div>
    <div class="row-end">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!--END SLIDER POST -->
```

### CSS

```
.slider_post_container{
background-image:url(images/slide_background.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding:80px 0px 50px 0px;  
}

.arrow_left{float:left; width:100px;}

.arrow_right{float:left; width:100px;}

input#slide_left{
background-image:url(images/slider_buttons.png);
background-color:transparent;
background-position:-60px 0px;
display:block; border:0px;
height:61px;
margin:150px auto 0px;
position:relative;
text-indent:-99999px;
width:60px;
}

input#slide_right{
background-image:url(images/slider_buttons.png);
background-color:transparent; 
background-position:0px 0px;
display:block; border:0px; 
height:61px; 
margin:150px auto 0px;
text-indent:-99999px; 
width:60px; 
 }

.slide_post{
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:1000px; 
}



.slide_post_wrap{min-width:5000px; float:left}

.slider_post{
  float:left; 
  margin:0 10px;  
  position:relative; 
  width:230px;
}

.slider_post h2{margin-bottom:10px; height:40px}

.slider_post  a.post_title{
  color:black;
  font-size:20px; 
  font-family:'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:normal;
}

.slider_post .post_thumbnail{width:230px; margin-bottom:10px}
.slider_post .post_thumbnail img{max-width:230px; overflow:hidden;}

.slider_post p{margin-bottom:10px; font-size:12px; height:140px}

a.read_more{
  color:#2e3192; 
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration:none; 
  text-transform:uppercase; 
}
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var $item = $('div.slider_post'),
    visible = 1,
    index = 0,
    endIndex = ( $item.length / visible ) -1

$('input#slide_left').click(function(){
    if(index < endIndex ){
        index++;
        $item.animate({'left':'-=235px'});
    }
});

$('input#slide_right').click(function(){
    if(index > 0){
        index--;
        $item.animate({'left':'+=235px'});
        }
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the width of your slides incorrectly, as you are neglecting the margin.

Either hard code them as suggested by @BenR, or determine the width programatically:

```
var w = $item.outerWidth( true );

$item.animate({'left':'-=' + w + 'px'});
$item.animate({'left':'+=' + w + 'px'});
```

Also, to have the slide stop at the last slide, you will have to change your end index variable.

You can either hard code this as 5, or do it programatically:

```
endIndex = $item.length - Math.floor($(".slide_post").width()/w);
```

Here's everything together:

```
var $item = $('div.slider_post'),
  w = $item.outerWidth( true ),
  visible = 1,
  index = 0,
  endIndex = $item.length - Math.floor($(".slide_post").width()/w);

$('input#slide_left').click(function(){
  if(index < endIndex ){
    index++;
    $item.animate({'left':'-=' + w + 'px'});

});


$('input#slide_right').click(function(){
  if(index > 0){
    index--;
    $item.animate({'left':'+=' + w + 'px'});
  }
});
```

Here's a [**demo**](http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/slider-demo3.html) of it working.

Comment: Alright thanks, javascript is still new to me and basically this slider is based on a tutorial i have read. Thanks for a working demo and also the effort :)

Comment: By the way how did you manage to recreate the exact layout of the slider especially fetching the images from wordpress.

Comment: I just linked to them on your site. Check the source code :)

Comment: Hahaha forgot to check the source code. Thanks a bunch :3

Answer (score 0):

Might be a css issue.
Put the width of the slider to 100% or if its static,just adjust the width such that it doesnt exceed the contents of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

You don't slide enough : your items are 250px wide not 235 (you forgot the margin).
Also endIndex is equal to 8 instead of 5 : you have to set it to $item.length - (number of item visible).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $item = $('div.slider_post'),
        visible = 1,
        index = 0,
        endIndex = 5;

    $('input#slide_left').click(function() {
        if (index < endIndex) {
            index++;
            $item.animate({
                'left': '-=250px'
            });
        }
    });

    $('input#slide_right').click(function() {
        if (index > 0) {
            index--;
            $item.animate({
                'left': '+=250px'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: $item.length - (number of item visible) wont this make my slider slide even further showing only blank items?